# JSSOR Slider removes the slide data while moving to next slide (I am appending slides on EVT_SWIPE_END event)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, css, jssor

I am trying to append the JSSOR slides on the EVT_SWIPE_END event (because I want to include slides dynamically). Right after I switch to next slide and comes back to previous one JSSOR slider removes the data of previous slides and upcoming slides.

https://plive.weddingoffice.com.cn/wechat/pages/vs2.html

```
var flag=0;
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

  var jssor_1_options = {
        $AutoPlay: 0,
        $DragOrientation: 2,
        $PlayOrientation: 2,
        $FillMode: 2,
        $Loop: 0,
        $SlideWidth: 375,
        $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
          $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
          $Orientation: 2
        }
  };

  var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
  //////////////////////trying to get append next slide/////////////////////////////
    function DisplayIndex(position, virtualPosition) {
         console.log("---------------");
        if(flag==0){
          flag=1;
          previous_position = parseInt(virtualPosition)+1;
        }
        else {
              var total_slides = jssor_1_slider.$SlidesCount();
              var current_slide = parseInt(virtualPosition)+1;
              if(previous_position==current_slide){
                console.log("do nothing");
              }
              if(previous_position>current_slide){
                console.log("previous");
              }
              if(previous_position<current_slide){
                console.log("next");
                var slidesHtml='<div><img data-u="image" src="img/010.jpg" /></div>';
                jssor_1_slider.$AppendSlides(slidesHtml, total_slides);
                jssor_1_slider.$GoTo(position);
              }
              previous_position = current_slide;
        }
    }
    jssor_1_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SWIPE_END, DisplayIndex);//$EVT_DRAG_END
  //////////////////////trying to get append next slide ends/////////////////////////////
};
```

jssor_1_slider_init();

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.
Please get version 28.0 here http://www.jssor.com/script/jssor.slider-28.0.0.min.js
We will publish 28.0 in a few months.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with the z-index of image, after appending few slides, the main cover image was showing above the main content of the slide.